# how to fix "Index was outside the bounds of the array" Error

Tags: c#

I recive the "Index was outside the bounds of the array" error in line `c[x,y]+=linei*lineu;`. the size of the result matrix must be [1,1143600].
I must read one line of first file and 1143600 lines (in the shape of matrix they must be columns) from the second one (every line has 100 float in both dataset)and they must multiply (like multiply two matrixes).

Also, how can i do the below code with skip method.

```
for (int counter = 0; counter <= i; counter++)
   {
      USER.ReadLine();
   }
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace DEMO_3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        float[,] c = new float[1, 1143600];
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btn_recomm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              //get the user input from text box
            int sc = Convert.ToInt32(txtbx_sc.Text);
            int i=sc*100;
            //read both dataset
            StreamReader USER = new StreamReader("c:\\1.txt");
            StreamReader ITEM = new StreamReader("c:\\2.txt");
              for (int counter = 0; counter <= i; counter++)
                {
                  USER.ReadLine();
                }

                for (int x = 0; x < 1143600; x++)
                   {
                      for (int y = 0; y < 100; y++)
                        {
                          float lineu=Convert.ToSingle(USER.ReadLine());
                          float linei=Convert.ToSingle(ITEM.ReadLine());
                          c[x,y]+=linei*lineu;

                    }
                }
                var allValues = c.OfType<float>();
                using (var filestream = new FileStream("DEMO.txt", FileMode.Create))
                using (var streamwriter = new StreamWriter(filestream))
                {
                    foreach (double valuec in allValues)
                        streamwriter.WriteLine(valuec);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:
inicialize your matrix :

```
float[,] c = new float[1143600, 100];
```

and change this looping code:

```
for (int y = 0; y < 100; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 1143600; x++)
    {
        float lineu=Convert.ToSingle(USER.ReadLine());
        float linei=Convert.ToSingle(ITEM.ReadLine());
        c[y,x]+=linei*lineu;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Lucas abilidebob . may you tell me why change the loop to this?